# ADF AutoSuggest not working on mobile

Tags: java, autocomplete, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, autosuggest

I'm building a web app and implemented to two inputText fields the AutoSuggestion functionality in Java. It works fine on desktop but when I run the page in mobile (with all its responsive tags Ex. matchmediaBehavior) it doesn't produce the functionality of AutoSuggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Oracle Mobile Application Framework (MAF)_ for mobile apps. 
That is the recommended  mobile approach.
Please read more [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need it to work on a responsive web page.